# Write python procedure to write python procedure

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, procedure

I am trying to write a procedure that will automate the procedure of making a tkinter window, so I am trying to use the open() function to open a txt file (probably should be a .py shouldn't it?) that a procedure that makes the window, the code I am trying to have it write is:

```
def a_procedure():
    window = Tk()
    #rest of code necessary to make a Tkinter window
```

but the problem is, when I use

```
open()
textfile.write("def a_procedure()"/
"window = Tk()")
```

what I get in the text file is: def a_procedure(): window = TK() #rest of text

Is there (a)A way to write multiple lines with 
    open() 
or (b)A better way to write a procedure with a procedure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multi-line strings:

```
textfile.write("""
def a_procedure():
    window = Tk()
""")
```

Just make sure to keep stuff indented properly.

Why do you need to generate Python from a Python script?

Answer (score 5):

Your example doesn't show how you're going to vary the generated function (since if they're all the same you don't need to generate them). So I'll show a different example where a function can return a new function.

```
def make_function(first_multiplicand):
    def multiply(second_multiplicand):
        return first_multiplicand * second_multiplicand

    return multiply
```

Then you can make functions that multiply by different amounts:

```
doubler = make_function(2)
tripler = make_function(3)
print doubler(7), tripler(7)
```

This way you don't have to write out a `.py` file and then `import` it (which has potential problems if you can't write out files anywhere helpful, as well as requiring you to create Python source code by string formatting, which is pretty ugly).

It's also worth looking at `functools`, particularly `functools.partial`; you could rewrite the above using it as follows:

```
import functools

def make_function(first_multiplicand):
    def multiply(first, second):
        return first * second
    return functools.partial(multiply, first_multiplicand)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: "def a_procedure():\n\twindow = Tk()"